# overload operator= inside template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> ClassA
{
    ...
    ClassA& operator=(const ClassA&);

    ...
};

// case one:
template<typename T>
ClassA<T>& ClassA<T>::operator=(const ClassA &rhs)
{ ... }

// case two:
template<typename T>
ClassA<T>& ClassA<T>::operator=(const ClassA<T> &rhs)
{ ... }
```

I assume case one is correct.

Question> Why we don't have to use `ClassA<T>` in the function parameter list such as in case two?

Comment: I have been told that "we must specify the template parameters for the name of a class template except inside the scope of the class itself. Here the function parameter is NOT inside the scope of classA, so I thought we MUST use case two instead of one."

Comment: @iammilind: you vote up because of the impliedness?

Comment: @phresnel. It was a short-hand :). +1 for good question. "Because it is implied", is what I think is the answer.

Comment: @iammilind: Ah, I see :D

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, either version will work.

Once we have passed the `ClassA<T>::` part of `ClassA<T>& ClassA<T>::operator=(const ClassA& rhs)` it behaves as if we were inside the class. For example, the operator can access all the members of the class.

You do have to specify the full name for the return value, because at that point we still don't know that this is a member function (or operator).

Answer (score 0):

It's implied when it's in function parameter scope (but not in the return type). See also using nested classes as a parameter type.